# JBoss/JaxWS/JaxB: SOAP and JSON binding to one webservice

Tags: json, soap, jboss, jaxb, jax-ws

**Hello.**

I've written a SOAP-webservice using JAX-WS and JAX-B, running on a JBoss 5.
Due to the overhead of SOAP I now try to enable the access to the webservice via JSON (but it should still be available via SOAP).

**My question now is the following:**

- Is it possible to use the same webservice class (with the, via JaxB defined, bean class as parameter) for both endpoints?
- Can I also use JAX-B to parse the JSON input / output at the same bean as I use it for the SOAP transfer?
- And if it is possible: How? Or where should I start?

Comment: Unfortunately not.
I decided to switch my architecture and use JaxRS to implement REST services...